# The counter of my spent bounties in Data Explorer is greater than that of in my profile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Usually the counter in Data Explorer is smaller than the counter in my main profile because of the existence of deferred synchronization.

Today I noticed an opposite fact as follows.

- From [my main profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/mozartstrasse?tab=bounties&sort=offered):

  [image]
- From [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors):

  [image]

Is it a bug?

Comment: One more: it is a pity that there are no gold badges for top investors.

Comment: Could it be that a bounty was removed from your list due to a deleted question...?

Comment: @Werner: Maybe and I don't know how to track the history.

Comment: Maybe a bounty was wasted due to a question without an answer. That might be considered as not *awarded* but still *spent*

Comment: @percusse: But several times ago such wasted bounties happened several times without this issue. Or this issue occurs because of a new policy.

Comment: This case behaves as my shadow runs faster than I.

Comment: May be bugbusters can help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a bounty on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61957/how-can-we-get-a-rounded-pdf-page) (visible to 10k users) worth 50 points that is not included in your profile because it is deleted.  It was there and it was spent, we do not show these items in user profiles though.